# Whether it is possible to change bundle identifier?

Tags: iphone, ios

Can I change my app to new bundle identifier without affecting old app, suppose if an user upgrade the app?

Comment: In App store, I want to replace old bundle identifier with new bundle identifier

Comment: OK, that's not a transfer. You just want to change the bundle id. You can't. The bundle id is the primary key for the app. If you change the bundle id, you have to submit the updated app as a new app. Existing users will not see it as an update.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy .......

Answer (score 1):

By Changing Bundle Identifier it'll not consider as an Update of an previous Application.
For Ex. If we run same Application in device with 2 different bundle identifier then it will create 2 app icons.

Answer (score 0):

The bundle identifier is an ID for your application used by the system as a domain for which it can store settings and reference your application uniquely.

So you cannot change the bundle ID but in the situation where you must have to use bundle ID better idea is to Delete the Previous Application & Add Application with New bundle ID.

Hope this helps.